# Confused with Trigonometry Manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$h(t)=65+36\sin(1.5t)-15\cos(1.5t)$$
Can also be written as:
$$h(t)=65+k\sin(1.5t-\alpha)$$ where k and $\alpha$ are unkwowns.

In the marking scheme it says that I can let: $$k\sin\theta=36$$ and $$k\cos\theta=15$$
I am confused as to why we can do this.

Comment: Is it $\cos(1.5t)$ instead of $\cos(1.5)t$?

Comment: yes thanks, I changed it now

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates?

Comment: You can think of it this way: You have two unknown variables $k$ and $\theta$ and two equations. So you can solve a system of equations.

Comment: Because $k\sin(1.5t-\alpha)=(k\cos(\alpha))\sin(1.5t)-(k\sin(\alpha))\cos(1.5t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All points $(k\sin(\theta),k\cos(\theta))$ are on a cirle with radius $k$.

Because $(36,15)$ lies on this circle you find $k=\sqrt{36^2+15^2}=39$. You find $\theta$ using $36=39\sin(\theta) \Rightarrow \theta \approx 67.38°$.